# Kubernetes - Set Pod replication criteria based on memory and cpu usage

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, devops, kubernetes-pod

I am newbie to Kubernetes world. Please excuse if I am getting anything wrong.

I understand that pod replication is handled by k8s itself. We can also set cpu and memory usage for pods. But is it possible to change replication criteria based on memory and cpu usage? For example if I want to a pod to replicate when its memory/cpu usage reaches 70%.

Can we do it using metrics collected by Prometheus etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [horizontal pod autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/). From the docs

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods
> in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set
> based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on
> some other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod
> Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can't be scaled, for
> example, DaemonSets.
>
> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler is implemented as a Kubernetes API
> resource and a controller. The resource determines the behavior of the
> controller. The controller periodically adjusts the number of replicas
> in a replication controller or deployment to match the observed
> average CPU utilization to the target specified by user

An example from the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/)

The following command will create a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler that maintains between 1 and 10 replicas of the Pods. HPA will increase and decrease the number of replicas to maintain an average CPU utilization across all Pods of 50%.

```
kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
```

Comment: Thanks Arghya. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Now I need to check and implement If I can auto scale my pods using custom metrics or metrics from prometheus.

Comment: @shujaat but make sure you have deployed the metric server otherwise HPA will not work.